# Rails: Controllers update action failing to update mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to rails so please bear with me.

I have a resource :examen with a has_one relation to a resource :aanwezigheidslijst.

In the aanwezigheids_controller i have everything prepared for editing "aanwezigheidslijst".

Now the problem I'm having is when editing (specificly showing whether or not a student was attending or not by checking a checkbox) each "aanwezigheidslijst" is when i submit the form it renders to 'index' (just like i want) but apparently no changes have been made to the mysql database.

There are no errors that pop up and the lay-out is like i want it, it's just the checkbox that represents the boolean "aanwezig" that isn't updated when i submit it.

The connection with the mysql database works fine with other parts of the app.

any solutions are very much appreciated.

EDIT

as proposed i took a look at the log file. I figure the Unpermitted parameters have something to do with it? can anyone clarify?

Log File:

```
Started PATCH "/aanwezigheidslijst/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-21 16:12:14 +0100
Processing by AanwezigheidslijstController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uxgvXaOPs66wtYBntTr907RN4yfC0vLTfresXPURBow=", "aanwezigheidslijst"=>{"1"=>{"student"=>"Tom Nys", "aanwezig"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"student"=>"Jan de Roeck", "aanwezig"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"student"=>"Nick van Heertum", "aanwezig"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Save Aanwezigheidslijst", "id"=>"2"}
  [1m[35mAanwezigheidslijst Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  `aanwezigheidslijsts`.* FROM `aanwezigheidslijsts`  WHERE `aanwezigheidslijsts`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: 1, 2, 3
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/aanwezigheidslijst/index
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

aanwezigheidslijst migration:

```
class CreateAanwezigheidslijsts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :aanwezigheidslijsts do |t|
      t.string :student
      t.boolean :aanwezig

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

aanwezigheids_controller.rb:

```
class AanwezigheidslijstController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @aanwezigheidslijst = Aanwezigheidslijst.all
    @examen = Examen.all
  end

  def edit
    @aanwezigheidslijst = Aanwezigheidslijst.where(:examen_id => params[:id]).all
  end

  def update
    @aanwezigheidslijst = Aanwezigheidslijst.find(params[:id])

    if @aanwezigheidslijst.update(aanwezig_params)
      redirect_to aanwezigheidslijst_index_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end

  end
    private

    def aanwezig_params
      params.require(:aanwezigheidslijst).permit(:student, :aanwezig)
    end

end
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="tblAanwezig">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="max-width: 300px;">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Student</th>
        <th scope="col">Aanwezig</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <%= form_tag edit_aanwezigheidslijst_url,  :id => 'al_form', method: :patch do %>
          <% @aanwezigheidslijst.each do |aanwezigheidslijst| %>
              <%= fields_for "aanwezigheidslijst[]",  aanwezigheidslijst do |al| %>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <%= al.text_field :student %></td>
                        <td><%= al.check_box :aanwezig %></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                          <% end %>
                      <% end %>
      </table>
          <%= submit_tag "Save Aanwezigheidslijst" %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 get 'aanwezigheidslijst/index'

 patch 'aanwezigheidslijst/:id/edit' => 'aanwezigheidslijst#update'

 get 'examen/index'

 get 'comments/new'
 post 'comments/new'

 get 'comments/update'

 get 'comments/create'

 get 'application/application'

 resources :comments
 resources :aanwezigheidslijst

 root 'comments#index'

end
```

Comment: take a look at the logs , they should show you what is getting passed in and will show you what queries are being run, etc..